# How do I install OpenBSD-httpd on Debian

Tags: debian, openbsd-httpd

I would like to run OpenBSD-httpd on Linux.

Is there a portable version of OpenBSD-httpd? How do I install it on Debian?

Comment: I'm not aware of a Debian package of this. The OpenBSD project does not seem to provide a "portable version" of `httpd` (as they do for things like OpenSSH, OpenSMTPD, OpenNTPD, LibreSSL, etc.).